# Is there an R function for separating smoothed functional data?

Tags: r

I have made two smoothed functional curves approximated by B-splines of order 8 and 349 equidistant knots from year 1971 to 2000. Now I would like to separate these functions into shorter intervals, e.g. every year and compute semi-metrics between those functions. Is there any function for this task in Rstudio?

I have tried to change rangeval in fd object but in function 
semimetric.basis(fd_1, fd_2, nderiv = 0) there is an error

> "Error in bsplineS(evalarg, breaks, norder, nderiv, returnMatrix):
>   Knots are not increasing".

```
basis <- create.bspline.basis(rangeval = c(1971, 2000),
                              nbasis = 355,
                              norder = 8) 
Lfdobj_f <- int2Lfd(4)
Sm_f <- smooth.basisPar(argvals = seq(from = 1971, to = 2000,length  = 349),              
                        y = cbind(func_1, func_2),
                        fdobj = basis,
                        Lfdobj = Lfdobj_f,
                        lambda = 1e-9)

Sm_f[1, 0]$fd$basis$rangeval <- c(1971, 1972)
Sm_f[2, 0]$fd$basis$rangeval <- c(1971, 1972)

output <- semimetric.basis(Sm_f[1, 0]$fd, Sm_f[2, 0]$fd, nderiv = 0)
```

I expected the output of real number.